# An explanation of why the Lucas-Lehmer Primality Test works: is this OK?

Tags: prime-numbers, primality-test, mersenne-numbers, lucas-lehmer-test

I've always wondered why the Lucas-Lehmer Primality Test works. After studying it, I came up with an explanation. I hope you can help me confirm and complete it.
A Mersenne prime is a number of the form M<sub>p</sub> = 2<sup>p</sup> – 1, when M<sub>p</sub> and p are primes.
The basic Lucas-Lehmer Test routine for evaluating a number M<sub>p</sub> is as follows:

```
a = 4  
M = 2p – 1  
repeat p – 2 times:  
   a = ( a2 – 2 ) mod M  
if a = 0 then M is a Mersenne prime, otherwise it is not.
```

To optimize the process, the module calculation is performed at each repetition. This prevents the value of **a** turns into an excessively large number.
If we didn't use the modulus, the equation A<sub>p+1</sub> = ( A<sub>p</sub><sup>2</sup> – 2 ) would generate **Sequence A** (OEIS A003010):

```
A0 = 4
A1 = 14
A2 = 194
A3 = 37634
A4 = 1416317954
A5 = 2005956546822746114
```

To evaluate the Mersenne prime M<sub>5</sub> = 31 = 2<sup>5</sup> – 1, the repetition is done 3 times (= 5 – 2), which corresponds to A<sub>3</sub> = 37634 which is divisible by 31.
The interesting point is that we can also use A<sub>n</sub> – 2 to carry out the evaluation. In this case, A<sub>5</sub> – 2 is divisible by 31.
Carry out the computation with A<sub>3</sub> instead of A<sub>5</sub> is more computationally efficient, as it involves much smaller values.

**Justification of why, when A<sub>n-2</sub> is divisible by M<sub>n</sub>, A<sub>n</sub> – 2 is also:**
For a Mersenne prime M<sub>n</sub>, according to Lucas-Lehmer, we have that:

```
An-2 is a multiple of Mn
An-1 = An-22 – 2
An = An-12 – 2
```

Consequently,

```
An = (An-22 – 2)2 – 2 = An-24 – 4 . An-22 + 2
```

And since A<sub>n-2</sub> is a multiple of M<sub>n</sub> let's replace A<sub>n-2</sub><sup>4</sup> – 4 . A<sub>n-2</sub><sup>2</sup> by k . M<sub>n</sub>:

```
An = k . Mn + 2
Or
An – 2 = k . Mn,      a multiple of Mn.
```

In modular arithmetic this is represented as A<sub>n</sub> – 2 ≡ 0 (mod M<sub>n</sub>).
So, if A<sub>3</sub> is divisible by 31, then A<sub>5</sub> – 2 is too.
Another example:
The Mersenne prime M<sub>3</sub> = 2<sup>3</sup> – 1 = 7 is a divisor of A<sub>1</sub> = 14 (where, 1 = 3 – 2).
And M<sub>3</sub> is also a divisor of A<sub>3</sub> – 2 = 37632.

**Now we will see the origin of the Sequence A property.**
There is another sequence, with a special property, which is generated by equation B<sub>m</sub> = 4 . B<sub>m-1</sub> – B<sub>m-2</sub>, Sequence B (OEIS A003500):

```
B1 = 4           = A0
B2 = 14          = A1
B3 = 52
B4 = 194         = A2
B5 = 724
B6 = 2702
B7 = 10084
B8 = 37634       = A3
B9 = 140452
B10 = 524174
B11 = 1956244
...
B31 = 537494436773078404
B32 = 2005956546822746114    = A5
```

Note that the values in sequence A are a subset of sequence B, as indicated. Matching with A occurs when the subscript m, of B<sub>m</sub>, has the value of a power of 2 (1, 2, 4, 8, etc.). Therefore, A<sub>3</sub> has the same value as B<sub>8</sub>, because 2<sup>3</sup>=8.

**Quick summary**
Prime numbers p divides the corresponding values of B<sub>p</sub> minus 4, that is
B<sub>p</sub> – 4 ≡ 0 (mod p).
For example, 31 is a divisor of (B<sub>31</sub> – 4) and 7 is a divisor of (B<sub>7</sub> – 4).
Mersenne primes furthermore divide the value of B<sub>p+1</sub> minus 2:
B<sub>p+1</sub> – 2 ≡ 0 (mod p).
In this case, 31 also divides (B<sub>32</sub> – 2). And 7 divides (B<sub>8</sub> – 2).
So, for all Mersenne primes, B<sub>p+1</sub> are powers of 2 and have the same values as A<sub>n</sub>, in which 2<sup>n</sup> = p + 1.
That is, 31 divides (B<sub>32</sub> – 2) which has the same value as (A<sub>5</sub> – 2), where 5 = log<sub>2</sub>(32).
And, if A<sub>n</sub> – 2 ≡ 0 (mod M<sub>n</sub>), we have that A<sub>n-2</sub> ≡ 0 (mod M<sub>n</sub>), as we saw previously, which is the Lucas-Lehmer Test.
The Test works because primes p divide the respective B<sub>p</sub> values minus 4.

**Some questions and comments:**
Although I have not found a proof that prime numbers divide their respective values of sequence B minus 4, I have verified that this is true up to 1000000. Does anyone know of a proof of this property?
Note that there are composite numbers that also divide the respective values of sequence B minus 4, for example, 10, 209, 230, etc. (OEIS A335673).
In addition, the prime m divides (B<sub>m</sub> – 4) and also divides another value, either (B<sub>m-2</sub> – 4) or (B<sub>m+2</sub> – 4). Some primes and the Mersenne primes divide (B<sub>m</sub> – 4) and also divide (B<sub>m+2</sub> – 4). For example, M<sub>3</sub> = 7, in addition to dividing B<sub>7</sub> – 4 (=10080), divides B<sub>9</sub> – 4 (=140448). Other primes divide (B<sub>m</sub> – 4) and (B<sub>m-2</sub> – 4), for instance, prime 11, which divides (B<sub>11</sub> – 4) and (B<sub>9</sub> – 4).
I have not found a demonstration of why this occurs, but the fact, proven by applying the Lucas-Lehmer Test, is that the Mersenne primes divide (B<sub>m</sub> – 4) and (B<sub>m+2</sub> – 4).

```
Therefore, knowing that
Bm+2  = 4 . Bm+1 – Bm and also that  
Bm – 4 ≡ 0 (mod M) and  
Bm+2 – 4 ≡ 0 (mod M) we can calculate that  
Bm+1 – 2 ≡ 0 (mod M).  
And, as Mersenne prime Bm+1 is the same as An then  
An – 2 ≡ 0 (mod M) and, consequently,  
An-2  ≡ 0 (mod M), which is the Lucas-Lehmer Test.
```